# How can I stop to update data before clicking on update button in edit form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on the vue.js template and I have one content edit and content add form. When I click on the edit button then on that time I passed the object to show data for editing in form but I used `v-modal` that shows instant changes before clicking on button update.

```
<v-form v-model="valid" @submit.prevent="updateContact(edit)">
    <v-card-text>
        <v-container grid-list-md>
            <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-text-field label="Name" v-model="edit.name"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-text-field label="Designation" v-model="edit.designation"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>

            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="onEditCancel()">Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="error" type="submit">Update</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-form>
```

When I click on edit button then I hit following function:

```
onEditContact(contact) {
    this.dialog1 = true;
    this.edit = contact;
},
```

Contact update method:

```
updateContact(edit){
    console.log(edit);
}
```

Comment: By default set the edit(submit) button in disabled state. Here v-model="valid" is a boolean which validates the form, try to validate the form and enable submit button once all the fields are valid

Comment: @chandrasekar Thank you for your fast response but fields are valid or not valid is the other thing I need to stop data changes instantly and just update data on click of the update button

Comment: :return-value.sync in v-modal component can resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the form data changes if that is not save, by adding additional attributes to v-dialog component

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog1"
  ref="editDetails"
  :return-value.sync="edit"
>
</v-dialog>
```

In updateContact, if the item is saved properly you can save perfs

```
this.$refs.editDetails.save(this.edit);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but `ref="editDetails"
  :return-value.sync="edit"` I tried with this code its not working. when I made changes in the field and then click on empty space to hide the pop up at that time it does not show the actual data. Its shows changed values.

Comment: hey!!  can you give me your skype username?

Comment: Here is my id     live:vchandras_1

Comment: can you give me your skype username?